# Sending OpenCV Mat in Android Bundle

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-intent, bundle

I want to send org.opencv.core.Mat object in Bundle. I decided to use Gson, because it seems easy and fast way.

Parent Activity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.areas_creator_activity:
            Gson gs = new Gson();
            String stringBackground = gs.toJson(guard.getBackground());
            Intent intentAreasCreatorActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AreasCreatorActivity.class);
            intentAreasCreatorActivity.putExtra("background", stringBackground);
            startActivityForResult(intentAreasCreatorActivity,2);
            break;
      }
        return true;

 }
```

Child activity:

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    String jsonMyObject= new String();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       jsonMyObject = extras.getString("myObject");
    }
    Gson gs = new Gson();
    Mat myObject = gs.fromJson(jsonMyObject, Mat.class);
    background=myObject;
    //Log.i("@string/app_name", background.toString());        
}
```

LogCat

```
    05-05 19:59:12.286: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-05 19:59:12.286: E/AndroidRuntime(7961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {pl.net.lach.pracainz/pl.net.lach.pracainz.AreasCreatorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

There is a problem when i use Mat metod on background object(commented line). What is wrong?

Comment: Mat contains a native c++ object (a pointer to a cv::Mat). i don't think, you can serialize that using Gson

Comment: how does it look, when you print out the json ?

Comment: in Parent Activity:

`05-05 21:23:19.892: INFO/@string/app_name(15577): stringBackground = {"nativeObj":1556479152}`

in Child is a Null. What are you suggesting?

Comment: i might be all wrong, but the original Mat might have been gc'ed in the meantime, leaving you with a dangling pointer

Comment: What will be good sollution? Transform it to Bitmap?

Comment: maybe. can't you just imwrite() to sdcard instead of serializing into the bundle ?

Comment: OMG There is a big mistake. There isn't key "myObject" in Intent. In parent key is "background" 5 hours to find bug like this...